# SyncFusion GridDataControl Grouping

Tags: c#, wpf, syncfusion

I'm using a [SyncFusion](http://help.syncfusion.com/User%20Interface/WPF/Grid) `GridDataControl` to display some data.

The rows in the grid are grouped on a column (say column `Group`)

I would like to not use a group when the column `Group` has a specific value (i.e. `null` or `""`) so the rows would always be shown and could not be collapsed.

Does anyone have an idea of how to do this?

So far I have hooked into the `Loaded` event on the `GridDataControl`:

```
private void OnGridLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    foreach ( Group group in AttributeGrid.Model.View.Groups)
    {
        if (@group.Key == null)
        {
            AttributeGrid.Model.Table.ExpandGroup(@group);
            // Do something here to hide the group?
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: have u tried using attached properties..

Comment: @Sandepku. I'm a bit of a beginner when it comes to WPF, could you expand on this?

Answer (score 2):

Please find the update below,

```
//Use the below code to Expand the particular group based on the key
void AssociatedObject_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    foreach (Group group in this.AssociatedObject.Model.View.Groups)
    {
        if (group.Key.Equals(1))
            this.AssociatedObject.Model.Table.ExpandGroup(group);
    }
}
```

For collapsing group at runtime,

```
//Use the below code to cancel the Grouping for particular group based on the keu
void Table_GroupCollapsing(object sender, GroupCollapsingEventArgs args)
{
    if (args.Group.Key.Equals(1))
        args.Cancel = true;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this. Is there anyway of removing the extra row in the table which has the [-] control in it?